# R: pwfdtest produces an error message even with the test data

Tags: r, plm

In R using the `plm` package, `pwfdtest` produces an error message even with the test data:
pwfdtest(log(emp) ~ log(wage) + log(capital), data = EmplUK, h0 = "fe")

Error message:

> "Error in order(nchar(cnames), decreasing = TRUE) :    4 arguments
>   passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3".

Bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question [myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491732/r-error-in-linearhypothesis-test-car-package-using-example-data-under-certain) with a similar test (linearHypothesis). Apparently the nchar function changed, so you need to install the newest version of R and then update all your packages.
After re-installing R,

```
update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE)
```